# Xenforo - Argument 1 passed to XF\Repository\UserAlert::alertFromUser() must be an instance of XF\Entity\User

Tags: symfony, xenforo

While trying to send alert to a user getting this error.

**Argument 1 passed to XF\Repository\UserAlert::alertFromUser() must be an instance of XF\Entity\User**

$user comes from self made entity result.

```
$alertRepo = \XF::app()->repository('XF:UserAlert');
   $alertRepo->alert($user,
   $visitor['user_id'],$visitor['username'],
   'thread',$torrent->Thread->thread_id,
   "reseed",$extra);
```

any help on this will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved i just had to give proper parameters

**passing $user->User** solved my issue

```
$alertRepo = \XF::app()->repository('XF:UserAlert');
   $alertRepo->alert($user->User,
   $visitor['user_id'],$visitor['username'],
   'thread',$torrent->Thread->thread_id,
   "reseed",$extra);
```